# Using SignalR with ElastiCache fails

Tags: c#, signalr, amazon-elasticache

We have C# application using `SignalR` and `Amazon's ElastiCache` as backplane. However even SignalR allows to mask out certain commands it stills sends a `CONFIG` to the `ElastiCache` which fails `SignalR` silently (`CONFIG` is not supported by `ElastiCache`). For now we compile our own binary of `SignalR` with the change of removing the auto reconfiguration routine.

I wonder if anyone else tripped over this issue and wanted to see how you solved it.

The best idea would be to write a proxy for `ElastiCache` (like the Twitter proxy) but that is a huge undertaking.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What engine is your ElastiCache instance using (Memcached or Redis)?

Comment: Redis is the engine.

Comment: Can you gave your connection string for redis ElastiCache with masking your confidential data?

Comment: i didnt understand what config sends SingleR, i have implemented SingleR for a call center but i didnt see any config??

Comment: I am curious why SignalR would interfere with elasticache, Elasticache is only a cache for your webserver, or do you use it in some special way?

Comment: Please gave us your redis client config lines from your app/web.config

Comment: @ikwillem Elasticache is a hosted Redis and Memcached service, not only a cache for a webserver

Answer (score 1):

In this case client is important and Baking your own SignalR definitly bad practice. Did you check this page http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-redis: This method uses StackExchange.Redis(StrongName) and StackExchange.Redis has many options for connection.

We are using same method described in the [page](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-redis) on AWS with Elasticache Redis and we don't have any issues you had...

Regards...